# JavaFx белое (прозрачное) окно

Tags: java, javafx

Столкнулся с проблемой, при запуске приложения, программа открывается, но графические элементы не отображаются, пока не переместить окно на пару миллиметров в сторону. Если нажать на кнопку в приложении, то тоже нет графического изменения, только после перемещения окна, появляется изменение, которое должно делаться по нажатию кнопки. ОС windows XP. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: обновите: ОС, драйвера на видеокарту, версию джавы

Comment: Такой комплекс действий сразу) Обновить ОС не вариант, проблема может встречаться не на одном компьютере. По всей сети около 600 компьютеров.

Comment: XP официально не поддерживается более + Java тоже не поддерживает XP. Java 7 максимум можно ставить вроде как. 8-я версия требует выше XP уже (но может можно нагуглить как установить).

Comment: На некоторый компах, где windows XP - программа запускается. Везде используется одна версия java машины.

Comment: возможно нужно лишний раз вызвать каокй-то метод repaint, но не знаю есть ли он для JavaFX

Comment: JRE версия какая и какая версия JavaFX, а то прям вот вижу как клещами вытягиваем инфу у вас :)

Comment: jre-8u92, jdk1.8.0_231. Программа нормальна отрабатывает на некоторых windows XP, вероятно, не хватает чего-то в самой ОС, где есть проблема. Хотелось бы понять чего именно.

Answer (score 0):

У меня было подобное - окну задавался размер который я указал только после того как я его перемещу на пару миллиметров(а так ставился размер такой, какой был бы если бы я его не указывал в коде), решил проблемму тем что сначала показал окно с помощью .show() а потом только задал размеры окну, правда вряд-ли это вам поможет, ну и ладно.

Answer (score 0):

Помогла установка галки "запуск в режиме совместимости с windows 2000".